# PowerBI compose expression

Tags: expression, power-automate

I am converting an html email to json.

I have this expression to get the first table

```
concat('<table',first(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'<table')))
```

How would I get the second or third table?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, second, third, etc...

```
split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'<table')?[0]

split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'<table')?[1]

split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'],'<table')?[2]
```